# Removing point from cloud which are closer than threshold distance

Tags: vtk, point-clouds

I am importing mesh file where each face is described by coordinates of its vertices. Most vertices are shared between points. Therefore, I would like to eliminate points which are closer than `threshold` to a point which has been already added to the cloud. That means that I need to efficiently perform closest-point lookup and point insertion at the same time.

I try to use `vtkPointLocator` which I've already used for static cloud; but I am at loss how is it supposed to be used incrementally. The [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.8/html/a01521.html) is quite terse, and examples (e.g. [this one](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/DataStructures/IncrementalOctreePointLocator)) don't cover this scenario. [This post](http://markmail.org/thread/zrfkbazg3ljed2mj) was somewhat helpful, but I still don't have a working solution - I get segfaults in `InsertNextPoint` (the case below), infinite recursion in `CheateChildNode` (when using `vtkIncrementalOctreePointLocator` instead of `vtkPointLocator`), or some VTK error (like `no points to subdivide`, when there are zero points).

This is approximately what I do:

```
// read from input file
std::vector<Vector3d> vertices;
// bounds of the data are known    
double bounds[6]={/*...*/}; 

const double threshold=1e-5;

auto locator=vtkSmartPointer<vtkIncrementalOctreePointLocator>::New();
auto polydata=vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
auto points=vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoint>::New();

polydata->SetPoints(points);
locator->SetDataSet(polydata);
locator->InitPointInsertion(points,bounds);

for(size_t i=0; i< i<vertices.size(); i++){
    double* vertex=vertices[i].data(); // pointer to data
    double dist; // unused
    vtkIdType id;
    // don't search if there are no points yet
    // FindClosestPointWithinRadius calls BuildLocator internally,
    // which needs some points to be present already
    if(points->GetNumberOfPoints()>0) id=locator->FindClosestPointWithinRadius(threshold,vertex,dist);
    else id=-1;
    if(id<0){
        // point not found, insert it into the locator
        locator->InsertNextPoint(vertex);
    }
}
```

If there is an obvious error in the way the error is organized, I will be happy for any suggestion. If not, I try to make a MWE.

From reading the source, it seems even incremental classes call `BuildLocator` at every lookup, if the pointset was modified, which might be expensive. A suggestion for a better class for combined insertion/lookup would be therefore also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you may want to look at [vtkCleanPolyData](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.10/html/classvtkCleanPolyData.html), with PointMergingOn and a given tolerance.

Comment: Will this correctly remap topology? I.e. if a face is defined by vertices (3,4,5) and 5 gets merged with 2, will it become (3,4,2)?

Comment: Yes. That's what it's supposed to do.